# How can I create an array of ratios inside a for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop

I would like to create an array or vector of musical notes using a for loop. Every musical note, A, A#, B, C...etc is a 2^(1/12) ratio of the previous/next. E.G the note A is 440Hz, and A# is 440 * 2^(1/12) Hz = 446.16Hz.

Starting from 27.5Hz (A0), I want a loop that iterates 88 times to create an array of each notes frequency up to 4186Hz, so that will look like

```
f= [27.5 29.14 30.87 ... 4186.01]
```

So far, I've understood this much:

```
   f  = [];
for i=1:87,
   %what goes here
   %  f = [27.5 * 2^(i/12)]; ?

end

return;
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to do a loop for this in matlab, you can simply do:

```
f = 27.5 * 2.^((0:87)/12)
```

The answer:

```
f =

  Columns 1 through 13

         27.5       29.135       30.868       32.703       34.648       36.708       38.891       41.203       43.654       46.249       48.999       51.913           55

  Columns 14 through 26

        58.27       61.735       65.406       69.296       73.416       77.782       82.407       87.307       92.499       97.999       103.83          110       116.54

  Columns 27 through 39

       123.47       130.81       138.59       146.83       155.56       164.81       174.61          185          196       207.65          220       233.08       246.94

  Columns 40 through 52

       261.63       277.18       293.66       311.13       329.63       349.23       369.99          392        415.3          440       466.16       493.88       523.25

  Columns 53 through 65

       554.37       587.33       622.25       659.26       698.46       739.99       783.99       830.61          880       932.33       987.77       1046.5       1108.7

  Columns 66 through 78

       1174.7       1244.5       1318.5       1396.9         1480         1568       1661.2         1760       1864.7       1975.5         2093       2217.5       2349.3

  Columns 79 through 88

         2489         2637       2793.8         2960         3136       3322.4         3520       3729.3       3951.1         4186
```

Answer (score 2):

```
maxind = 87;
f = zeros(1, maxind); % preallocate, better performance and avoids mlint warnings
for ii=1:maxind
  f(ii) = 27.5 * 2^(ii/12);
end
```

The reason I named the loop variable `ii` is because [`i`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html) is the name of a builtin function. So it's considered bad practice to use that as a variable name.

Also, in your description you said you want to iterate 88 times, but the above loop only iterates 1 through 87 (both inclusive). If you want to iterate 88 times change `maxind` to 88.